# How do I set Microsoft Teams General Channel Permissions through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online

I am disabling permissions for everyone to chat on "General" Teams channel manually by

1. clicking on (...)
2. Manage channel
3. selecting 'Only owners can post messages'

How can I do the same with PowerShell without any manual clicks?.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `CsTeamsMessagingPolicy` cmdlets enable administrators to control if a user is enabled to exchange messages.

```
Set-CsTeamsMessagingPolicy
   [-AllowUserChat <Boolean>]
```

**-AllowUserChat**

Determines whether a user is allowed to chat. Set this to TRUE to allow a user to chat across private chat, group chat and in meetings. Set this to FALSE to prohibit all chat.

For example:

```
Set-CsTeamsMessagingPolicy -Identity StudentMessagingPolicy
-AllowUserChat $false -AllowMemes $false
```

In this example two different property values are configured: AllowUserChat is set to false and AllowMemes is set to False. All other policy properties will be left as previously assigned.

Ref:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/set-csteamsmessagingpolicy?view=skype-ps

Comment: I am thinking of disabling posting of messages for a particular channel for all the users, it seems like the above cmdlet is setting a policy for every user.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to disable posting messages for all the users in a channel using PowerShell cmdlet.